# Toggle Switch in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, toggle

I have written below code in PHP + Ajax

```
<table>
  <tr><td data-id="1" onclick="showData(event);">ABC</td>
  <tr style='display:none' data-fold='1'><td>ABC - 01</td>
  <tr><td data-id="2" onclick="showData(event);">PQR</td>
  <tr style='display:none' data-fold='2'><td>PQR- 01</td>
</table>
```

I need to show data-fold "tr" when someone click on data-id with respective id, that is when I click on data-id 1, then data-fold 1 should be visible.

Also, the content in data-fold is coming from AJAX..

Below is my AJAX code:

```
function showData(event){

var rowId = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-id'); 
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php", // 
        data: 'type=viewOrder&rowId='+rowId,            
        success: function(msg){ 

            $("tr").each(function(){                    
                childId = $(this).attr('data-fold');   
                if(childId == rowId) {
                    $(this).toggle("slow");
                    $(this).html(msg);
                }
            });

        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });

   }
```

My code is working fine, but I need to close all other tr expect the one I clicked.

Comment: You are making the AJAX call with every click?  What does your event binding / click binding look like?

Comment: Yes... as this will be multi tr data, there is will atleast 25+ tr

Comment: So, please answer my other question: What does your event binding / click binding look like?

Comment: i have used onclick in tr and calling it as a function in js

Comment: OK, now I've asked three times: Show your code for your event binding, and if the code above is in a function, please show that.  Your question is very clear to you, but NOT to use, so please show us the code, or we can't help very well.

Comment: i have updated the complete code in above question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126585/discussion-between-dhawal-mhatre-and-cale-b).